# How to delete selected HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement the function by Javascript as below screenshot.

In one Input element, there some others elements, then want to do:

1. Select all the elements in the Input field.
2. Press 'Delete' key to delete the selected elements.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely, so please make a comment if I am not answering your question.

What I believe you want to do is delete an HTML element by selecting it, and then pressing the `delete` key.

```html
<div contentEditable="true" style="outline: none">
  <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/385/game_stars/64/mario.png" />
  <img src="http://orig14.deviantart.net/f682/f/2010/331/4/e/darth_vader_icon_64x64_by_geo_almighty-d33pmvd.png" />
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/the-blacy/64/grimace-icon.png" />
</div>
```

What I did was I added the Attribute `contenteditable` which allows the contents inside of the `<div>` to be edited by the user.

Comment: Hi Viraj,  Thanks very much for your prompt answer.  It solved most of the problem, except a little UI issue remained.

Comment: After I  added 'contentEditable=true' to the parent element, seletion and deletion works.  The UI looks not good.  please see below: